# Available actions for onUpdate / onDelete in Laravel 5.x

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-migrations

As mentioned in [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#foreign-key-constraints), we can use the word `cascade` when making a relation in migrations
but I wonder they didn't say anything about other actions when `deleting` or `updating` a foreign key

so I'm not sure if there is such thing or not:

```
$table->foreign('user_id')
  ->references('id')->on('users')
  ->onDelete('set null');
  //->onDelete('set_null');
  //->onDelete('setNull');
```

or the same thing about `onUpdate` and about `no action` just like the `phpMyAdmin`

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can do all the options mentioned in `phpmyadmin` this way:

```
$table->...->onDelete('CASCADE');
$table->...->onDelete('SET NULL');
$table->...->onDelete('RESTRICT');

// do not call the onDelete() method if you want the RESTRICT option.
```

You have to make sure you set the foreign key field as nullable:

```
$table->...->unsigned()->nullable();
```

Comment: Your comment is not correct - if you do not call `onDelete` then it defaults to "RESTRICT", at least in MySQL.

Answer (score 6):

Referring to the source code:

```
`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Grammars/Grammar.php` in the function compileForeign()
```

It just appends whatever you pass in to the table query.

```
    if (! is_null($command->onDelete)) {
        $sql .= " on delete {$command->onDelete}";
    }

    if (! is_null($command->onUpdate)) {
        $sql .= " on update {$command->onUpdate}";
    }
```

So, make sure you pass one of the following:  **"cascade", "no action", "restrict", or "set null"**

NOTE: Do ***NOT*** use underscores in the actions like ***"set_null" and "no_action"***

Answer (score 4):

onUpdate is also available

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
->onDelete('SET NULL')
->onUpdate('SET NULL'); // also available CASCADE, RESTRICT, DO NOTHING, NO ACTION
```

To use 'SET NULL' you have to make sure field is nullable

```
$table->integer('user_id')->nullable();
```